# Jquery Accordion issues with ie 6

Tags: jquery-ui

I have implemented a Jquery accordion on one of my pages using the following options

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", alwaysOpen: false, active: false, autoHeight: false});
```

This works brilliantly in Firefox and in ie7 ([now that I've upgraded to v1.7 of jquery ui](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4331))

However in ie6, pretty much all the contents of each accordion disappear (I'm left with a single `<select>` tag showing?!)

If I change the AutoHeight option to true as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332448/jquery-accordion-ie-animation-issues/694323#694323), then it's all fine again, except that I lose the nice benefit of having the accordions sized nicely, and some of them have loads of white space in them.

Does anyone know a fix so that I can still have AutoHeight = false?

Answer (score 14):

Adding .ui-accordion-content{ zoom: 1; } to my CSS fixed the problem for me:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
<style type="text/css">
        .ui-accordion-content{ zoom: 1; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Facing the same problem I found a solution that works across all browsers without having to change the autoHeight parameter.

just add a class to your css like this:

```
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
```

And then add it  to the content div following the h3 (like this: )

```
<h3>Header</h3>
<div class="clearfix">Whatever</div>
```

The problem is actually an IE6 issue with invisible text rendering. I have tested it on content containing unordered lists and complex nested divs and more, all working fine. Let me know if that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. The accordion works great with ul though so I found this article about how to make a table without using .

http://mindrulers.blogspot.com/2008/03/create-table-using-css.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to an IE6 rendering bug.  This fixed the problem for me.

```
// This is required for IE6.
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
    jQuery('#accordion *').css('zoom', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to use autoHeight true for IE6 and false for all other browsers.

```
var autoHeight = false;
if($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) <= 7.0) { autoHeight = true; }
$("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: autoHeight });
```