# Jquery accordion with image, strange behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

We have a jquery accordion that contains multiple items.  Each item in the accordion is structured like this:

```
<div class="menuSection accordion" default="closed" state="invisible">
    <div class="title">
            <h2><img class="titleIcon" src="/contact.jpg">Neem contact op</h2>
        <span class="accordion_openclose closed"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="menuContent" style="display: none; ">
        Content!
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I collapse one of the items in older versions of IE the image that is in the bar is lagging behind (around 5 seconds). This happens also in compatibility mode. Not in any other browsers.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: You can start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332448/jquery-accordion-ie-animation-issues.

Comment: Could you show us an example on [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: Are there specific versions of IE that cause the problem?

Comment: IE in compat mode. And so I think IE7..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `position:relative` attribute within the `.titleIcon` class.

IE7 doesn't seem to like it. I couldn't reproduce the bug in IE8+.

Comment: addeed a float left and margin top to fix that ;)